# Unfortunately, app name has stopped in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a problem with the application I'm trying to run. I had tried many solutions available here but no luck. Maybe you can help. Better If you also try to import it in eclipse. bts, I'm new to eclipse and this program isn't mine, but i have permission. Please do help :|

Here's my logcat:

> ```
> 09-19 09:28:44.355: E/Term(2264): onCreate
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264): Process: jackpal.androidterm, PID: 2264
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jackpal-androidterm4 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jackpal.androidterm-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jackpal.androidterm-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:610)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Exec.<clinit>(Exec.java:33)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Exec.createSubprocess(Native Method)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.ShellTermSession.createSubprocess(ShellTermSession.java:198)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.ShellTermSession.initializeSession(ShellTermSession.java:135)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.ShellTermSession.<init>(ShellTermSession.java:87)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term.createTermSession(Term.java:489)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term.createTermSession(Term.java:498)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term.populateViewFlipper(Term.java:411)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term.access$5(Term.java:405)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term$2.onServiceConnected(Term.java:150)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1202)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1219)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
> 09-19 09:28:46.278: E/AndroidRuntime(2264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
> ```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="jackpal.androidterm"
>   android:versionName="1.0.62"
>   android:versionCode="63"
>   android:installLocation="auto">
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> <permission android:name="jackpal.androidterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT"
>             android:label="@string/perm_run_script"
>             android:description="@string/permdesc_run_script"
>             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
>             android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
> <permission android:name="jackpal.androidterm.permission.APPEND_TO_PATH"
>             android:label="@string/perm_append_to_path"
>             android:description="@string/permdesc_append_to_path"
>             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
>             android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
> <permission android:name="jackpal.androidterm.permission.PREPEND_TO_PATH"
>             android:label="@string/perm_prepend_to_path"
>             android:description="@string/permdesc_prepend_to_path"
>             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
>             android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
> <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>             android:label="@string/application_terminal"
>             android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
>     <activity android:name="Term"
>             android:theme="@style/Theme"
>             android:launchMode="singleTask"
>             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
>             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity-alias android:name="TermInternal"
>             android:targetActivity="Term"
>             android:exported="false">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="jackpal.androidterm.private.OPEN_NEW_WINDOW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="jackpal.androidterm.private.SWITCH_WINDOW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity-alias>
>     <activity android:name="RemoteInterface"
>             android:excludeFromRecents="true">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="jackpal.androidterm.OPEN_NEW_WINDOW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity-alias
>             android:name="TermHere"
>             android:label="@string/activity_term_here_title"
>             android:targetActivity="RemoteInterface"
>             android:exported="true"
>
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
>             <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity-alias>
>     <activity-alias android:name="RunScript"
>             android:targetActivity="RemoteInterface"
>             android:permission="jackpal.androidterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity-alias>
>     <activity android:name="TermPreferences"
>             android:label="@string/preferences"/>
>     <activity android:name="WindowList"
>             android:label="@string/window_list" />
>     <service android:name="TermService" />
> <activity
>   android:label="@string/activity_shortcut_create"
>   android:name="jackpal.androidterm.shortcuts.AddShortcut"
>   android:launchMode="singleTop"
>   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
>   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
>
>   <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>   </intent-filter>
>   <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
>   </intent-filter>
>   <intent-filter>
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     <data     android:mimeType="text/*" />
>   </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> <activity
>   android:name="jackpal.androidterm.shortcuts.FSNavigator"
>   android:label="@string/addshortcut_button_find_command"
>   android:launchMode="singleTop"
>   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
>   android:exported="true"
>
>   <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>   </intent-filter>
>   <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
>     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
>   </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> <meta-data
>   android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
>   android:value="true">
>     </meta-data>
> </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: You are trying to load a native library that doesn't exist or cannot be found. Show us the code where you try to load this library.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't my program. I just downloaded it and I'm new in eclipse that's why i have no idea. Maybe i can share the link of the codes and steps on how to build it and figure it out. I'm sorry for this. codes (https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator), building using eclipse (https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/blob/master/docs/Building.txt). I hope you can help me with this. :( Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jackpal-androidterm4 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jackpal.androidterm-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jackpal.androidterm-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

the library file that you want to use is not loading thats why it returns null.

Comment: Thanks. Whenever I cleaned my project, there is an error saying: `Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Nikko\Desktop\Workspace\emulatorview\bin\emulatorview.jar' Term  Build path Build Path Problem` I know the library is missing but i don't know where to find that. Whenever I deleted it, error has gone but in my logcat it shows didn't find class. Sorry I'm new. Check for my other comment if you want to try it. Sorry

Comment: put that jar file on desktop and build the path from eclipse. in library tab add external jar file then from Order and Export tab click to check that jar file. hopefully you get your solution.

Comment: Thanks, but still having an issue. I don't know where to find that .jar file. I checked the bin, it has the folder classes>jackpal>androidterm>emulatorview It is just a folder, not a jar file

Comment: Could you please try it? It's an open source code, here's the link (https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator), building using eclipse (https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/blob/master/docs/Building.txt) I hope you can help us on this :(( Thanks

Comment: if this answer helps you then mark is as accepted that others can also use it if they have same problem